# How to mark a reference as unindexed in Spring data cloud datastore

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, google-cloud-datastore

We have @Unindexed annotation to mark a field as unindexed. But it doesn't work with a reference type field.
Source:- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Greenwich.RC1/multi/multi__spring_data_cloud_datastore.html

```
@Entity(name = "kind_one")
class Test {
   @Unindexed
   private String someFieldOne; //works - property is unindexed

   @Unindexed
   private List<TestTwo> someFieldTwo; //doesn't work - property is still indexed
}

@Entity(name = "kind_two") 
class TestTwo{
   @Unindexed 
   private String someFieldThree;
}
```

When storing the **Test** object in datastore, "someFieldOne" is marked as unindexed, but "someFieldTwo" is marked as indexed.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Lists the entire list must not be excluded from being indexed instead its values must be individually excluded from being indexed as mentioned in the comments [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spring-cloud-gcp/blob/e9c08349432e3da6a8b6b84a930b702e9cb14418/spring-cloud-gcp-data-datastore/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spring/data/datastore/core/convert/DefaultDatastoreEntityConverter.java#L259). Otherwise it will throw an exception.

I believe this is the reason why `someFieldTwo` is getting indexed in your case as it is a List barring the fact that it should throw an exception as per the comment.

So I would suggest you exclude the list elements individually as mentioned in [this example](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes#unindexed_properties) instead of annotating the whole list with `@unindexed`.

Comment: // ListValues must have its contents individually excluded instead.
// the entire list must NOT be excluded or there will be an exception.

As per the above statements, I should get an exception. But I don't. 

And I've actually marked each field as "Unindexed" in "TestTwo".

Comment: I am not sure why it is not throwing exception. And I cloud not understand `I've actually marked each field as "Unindexed" in "TestTwo"`. Can you explain it clearly?